# use ContinuousValueEncoder in mahout

Tags: mahout

I am trying to classify Mnist data set using mahout library. a it has 784 features each continuous variable. I am encoding the vector using ContinuousValueEncoder. So I have a doubt if I have to create 784 ContinuousVectorEncoder Instance.

*encoder_feature_1.addToVector((byte[]) null,value1,v);*

*encoder_feature_2.addToVector((byte[]) null,value2,v);*

*encoder_feature_3.addToVector((byte[]) null,value3,v);*

...........

...........

...........

*encoder_feature_784.addToVector((byte[]) null,value784,v);*

//where v is RandomAccessSparseVector with cardinality 784

Is it the correct way? or do I need to make single instance of the encoder.
I have not understood the concept properly its seems.